# How to disaable ATI catalyst keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Installed ATI Catalyst drivers to support my dual-monitor setup. The problem is now that WIN_KEY+P now interferes with keyboard shortcuts I am using for other programs. It basically toggles dual-display/clone-mode for my two monitors.

Does anyone know how I can change or disable this setting for catalyst?